# Restful - Converting Hibernate entities to JSON

Tags: java, spring, rest, serialization, jackson

What's the best way to do this using Spring and Jackson libraries.

For example:

```
Class A{
  Long id;
  String name;
  List<B> listOfB;
}

Class B{
 Long id;
 String description;
 List<C> listOfC;
}

Class C{
  Long id;
}
```

When I make a GET call to A, it should give me information of A's and and list of B's for each A. But B should not include list of C's

When I make a GET call to B, it should give me information of B's and list of C's for each 
B.

I know I can manually iterate and create a Jackson Json node object, but is there a framework that can help with this process? I have seem MVC 4 use ViewModel system to this. What is generally used in the Java world for RESTful services?

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to include [jackson-mapper-asl](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22jackson-mapper-asl%22) dependency to your classpath, and declare your Spring MVC handler method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
@ResponseBody
public A getA(..) {
  A a = // fetch A object from persistence layer
  return a;
}
```

The existence of `@ResponseBody` annotation will cause the object be translated into JSON

Comment: I have used this for simple objects, but this does not work properly when there are lists inside lists and when Lazy loading is involved. I looked at Jackson Hibernate utility but I didn't really like it.